# Calculate the time needed to run a certain function

Tags: php, function, performance

I that possible?
for eg. if I want to test if `str_replace()` is faster that `preg_replace()` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a PHP per-function (or per-task) performance / benchmark reference exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530610/does-a-php-per-function-or-per-task-performance-benchmark-reference-exist)

Comment: Sorry, disregard the duplicate, I thought the benchmark services provided the source code they use, but they don't.

Comment: You want a profiler like Zend_Debugger or XDebug for that. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=profile+php+script

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can run the same line 10,000 times (or more) in your script, and use `microtime(true)` to tell the time it took.

Reference: [microtime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

Comment: +1 This is the standard method. It's important to do it a large number of times (ie in a loop) so that (a) you get a measurable difference, and (b) so you can filter out variances in speed between one run and another.

Comment: thanks! it seems there's almost no difference between the 2 functions I mentioned :) str_replace seems just a little faster sometimes

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, but interpreter's has an optimizer's, that can find that you loop can be optimized, because there is no variables changed in loop iterations. So, better way is to use code-profilers like XDebug

Answer (score 30):

The easy way:

```
$time = microtime(true); // time in Microseconds

// Your code here

echo (microtime(true) - $time) . ' elapsed';
```

The hard(er) way:
Use a code profiler to see exactly how much time your methods will take.

Answer (score 7):

I found this answer by 'bisko' in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721351/how-can-i-measure-the-execution-time-of-a-for-loop) thread.

> $start = microtime(true);
>
> for (...) {
>     ....
>   }
>
> $end = microtime(true);
>
> echo ($end - $start).' seconds';

The for-loop can be replaced by whatever you want to time.