# Error "undefined reference to omp_get_wtime"

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp

I cannot find which library to link in GCC (4.8) under Windows ([Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista)). I tried the *-fopenmp -llibgomp -lgomp* compiler directives, but none works.

I already have GCC with POSIX (so *std::thread* is working if enabling C++11). The problem seems that searching for the right library does not provide useful results (even searching in GCC/[MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) documentation).

So basically I can't get [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/483286/1829943) working (the answer claimed to work on most compilers, but it doesn’t provide additional information on how to get it working, so I can't verify if it is really working or not).

It would be nice to provide now additional information to get it working on most systems...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MinGW-w64 based on GCC 4.8.1 from **[here](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds)** has no problems so far.

### Example: C

---

### main.c

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main() {
  double x = omp_get_wtime();

  printf("%f\n", x);
}
```

Build:

```
gcc main.c -lgomp -o test.exe
```

Result:

```
1381572544.299000
```

### Example: C++

---

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int
main() {
  double x = omp_get_wtime();

  cout << x << endl;
}
```

Build:

```
g++ main.cpp -lgomp -o test.exe
```

Result:

```
1.38158e+009
```

### Conclusion

---

Probably something is wrong with your MinGW distribution. Otherwise I don't see any reason for it not to work. Try the above one and see how it goes.

Comment: I re-downloaded GCC 4.8 distribution, now it compiled but measured times have a resolution of 15 milliseconds :/ no more than ctime

Comment: The feature you want to test is very implementation dependent. Maybe both of them already use high-resolution OS clock by default under the hood, and that's why you don't see any difference. Another possibility is that your benchmark has some wrong assumptions and/or is measuring too small unit of workload to capture the difference between these 2 timers.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks. I didn't know one has to add this.