# How can I resolve omp_get_wtime undefined in C?

Tags: c, openmp

I have a program in C with an [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) library. I am trying to measure the execution time for a loop to add numbers except that I am getting an error that the reference the function `omp_get_wtime()` is undefined while I have the library file included in the header section of my code file...

Why am I getting this error and how can I resolve it?

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    // Number of threads to use
    int no_threads = 3;

    // Mark the execution go mark
    double start = omp_get_wtime();

    // Parallelize the loop
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(no_threads)

    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        printf("%d", i);
    }

    double end_time = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("%f", end_time - start);
}
```

I tried to compile even before I started using the ***#pragma*** directive and got the error that the omp function is undefined and the function in the file.

Comment: is this duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332319/undefined-reference-to-omp-get-wtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build an OMP program with a flag.

```sh
gcc -fopenmp test.c
```

Comment: or head over to compiler options and add the string fopenmp when the compiler is invoked